# vectorized look-up of values in pandas dataframe: another example

Tags: python, pandas, lookup, vlookup

I've looked for example at 
[Vectorized look-up of values in Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893227/vectorized-look-up-of-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

but somehow my problem is a little bit different and i can't find the right way to do it, it's a simple vlookup

so i have a DataFrame

```
PoliceStations_raw=pd.DataFrame(
[['BAYVIEW'   ,37.729732,-122.397981],
 ['CENTRAL'   ,37.798732,-122.409919],
 ['INGLESIDE' ,37.724676,-122.446215],
 ['MISSION'   ,37.762849,-122.422005],
 ['NORTHERN'  ,37.780186,-122.432467],
 ['PARK'      ,37.767797,-122.455287],
 ['RICHMOND'  ,37.779928,-122.464467],
 ['SOUTHERN'  ,37.772380,-122.389412],
 ['TARAVAL'   ,37.743733,-122.481500],
 ['TENDERLOIN',37.783674,-122.412899]],columns=['PdDistrict','XX','YY'])
```

i also defined

```
PoliceStations=PoliceStations_raw.transpose()
```

Then i have another table df which has a column 'PdDistrict' containing a categorical variable which can take values like 'BAYVIEW', 'CENTRAL' etc...

i would like to have a column
df['XX'] which would return for each row of df the corresponding entry in the PoliceStations_raw...

i can't find the right syntax ... thanks for your help

if possible, i prefer the syntax involving PoliceStations_raw (instead of the transposed table), as i think this table is more "natural"...

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
df_raw['value'] = PoliceStations.lookup('XX',df_raw['PdDistrict'])
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 df_raw['value'] = PoliceStations.lookup('XX',df_raw['PdDistrict'])
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc
>   in lookup(self, row_labels, col_labels)    2641         n =
>   len(row_labels)    2642         if n != len(col_labels):
>   -> 2643             raise ValueError('Row labels must have same size as column labels')    2644     2645         thresh = 1000
>
> ValueError: Row labels must have same size as column labels

although I think i've made no labelling mistakes

```
df_raw['PdDistrict'].cat.categories
```

> Index([u'BAYVIEW', u'CENTRAL', u'INGLESIDE', u'MISSION', u'NORTHERN',
>   u'PARK',
>          u'RICHMOND', u'SOUTHERN', u'TARAVAL', u'TENDERLOIN'],
>         dtype='object')

EDIT:

I am also trying the following:

```
PoliceStations_raw=pd.DataFrame(
[['BAYVIEW'   ,37.729732,-122.397981],
 ['CENTRAL'   ,37.798732,-122.409919],
 ['INGLESIDE' ,37.724676,-122.446215],
 ['MISSION'   ,37.762849,-122.422005],
 ['NORTHERN'  ,37.780186,-122.432467],
 ['PARK'      ,37.767797,-122.455287],
 ['RICHMOND'  ,37.779928,-122.464467],
 ['SOUTHERN'  ,37.772380,-122.389412],
 ['TARAVAL'   ,37.743733,-122.481500],
 ['TENDERLOIN',37.783674,-122.412899]],columns=['PdDistrict','XX','YY'])


df1=pd.DataFrame([[0,'CENTRAL'],[1,'TARAVAL'],[3,'CENTRAL'],[2,'BAYVIEW']])
df1.columns = ['Index','PdDistrict']


  Index PdDistrict
0   0   CENTRAL
1   1   TARAVAL
2   3   CENTRAL
3   2   BAYVIEW
```

despite having typed in sort=False, the returned object has merged the table but is using PdDistrict as some Index and has changed the order of the rows of the original left dataframe.

help please !

```
pd.merge(df1,PoliceStations_raw,sort=False)
```

is returning me this

```
  Index PdDistrict  XX        YY
0   0   CENTRAL 37.798732   -122.409919
1   3   CENTRAL 37.798732   -122.409919
2   1   TARAVAL 37.743733   -122.481500
3   2   BAYVIEW 37.729732   -122.397981
```