# Vectorized lookup another row + calculated field

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DataFrame "dfSummary" -

```
exchangeBalances = [['ETHBTC','binance',10], ['LTCBTC','binance',10], ['XRPBTC','binance',10], ['ETHBTC','bitfinex',10], ['LTCBTC','bitfinex',10], ['XRPBTC','bitfinex',10]]
bidOffers = [
             ['ETHBTC','binance', 0.0035, 0.0351, datetime(2018, 9, 1, 8, 15)], ['LTCBTC','binance',0.009,0.092, datetime(2018, 9, 1, 8, 15)], ['XRPBTC','binance',0.000077, 0.000078, datetime(2018, 9, 1, 8, 15)], ['ETHBTC','bitfinex', 0.003522, 0.0353, datetime(2018, 9, 1, 8, 15)], ['LTCBTC','bitfinex',0.0093,0.095, datetime(2018, 9, 1, 8, 15)], ['XRPBTC','bitfinex',0.000083, 0.000085, datetime(2018, 9, 1, 8, 15)],
             ['ETHBTC','binance', 0.0035, 0.0351, datetime(2018, 9, 1, 8, 30)], ['LTCBTC','binance',0.009,0.092, datetime(2018, 9, 1, 8, 30)], ['XRPBTC','binance',0.000077, 0.000078, datetime(2018, 9, 1, 8, 30)], ['ETHBTC','bitfinex', 0.003522, 0.0353, datetime(2018, 9, 1, 8, 30)], ['LTCBTC','bitfinex',0.0093,0.095, datetime(2018, 9, 1, 8, 30)], ['XRPBTC','bitfinex',0.000083, 0.000085, datetime(2018, 9, 1, 8, 30)], 
             ['ETHBTC','binance', 0.0035, 0.0351, datetime(2018, 9, 1, 8, 45)], ['LTCBTC','binance',0.009,0.092, datetime(2018, 9, 1, 8, 45)], ['XRPBTC','binance',0.000077, 0.000078, datetime(2018, 9, 1, 8, 45)], ['ETHBTC','bitfinex', 0.003522, 0.0353, datetime(2018, 9, 1, 8, 45)], ['LTCBTC','bitfinex',0.0093,0.095, datetime(2018, 9, 1, 8, 45)], ['XRPBTC','bitfinex',0.000083, 0.000085, datetime(2018, 9, 1, 8, 45)]
             ]
dfExchangeBalances = pd.DataFrame(exchangeBalances, columns=['symbol','exchange','balance'])
dfBidOffers = pd.DataFrame(bidOffers, columns=['symbol','exchange','bid', 'offer', 'created'])
dfBidOffers["spread"] = dfBidOffers["bid"] - dfBidOffers["offer"]
dfSummary = dfExchangeBalances.merge(dfBidOffers, how='left', on=['symbol','exchange'])
```

What I need to accomplish is, add a **computed field** to "dfSummary":

```
currentRow["Spread"] - someOtherRow["Spread"]
```

**"someOtherRow"** is a **look up** based on "created" (For example last row with same {symbol, exchange} but "created" 30min ago (compared to "currentRow")

**Clarification**: Above example is **simplification** of real problem at hand. Intervals are not exactly 15 minutes. In fact I need to look up corresponding record (same key = {symbol, exchange}) in DataFrame, but first such record created on 1st month, quarter, and year.

I'm trying to avoid manually looping over DataFrame.iter and use Pandas built in lookup instead (Vectorization)

I'm thinking DataFrame.**Lookup**
    [Vectorized look-up of values in Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893227/vectorized-look-up-of-values-in-pandas-dataframe)
But not sure how to use this from context of a **calculated field** ...? Also instead of lookup against a **different** DataFrame, I want a lookup against **same** DataFrame.

Vectorization (Pandas and Numpy - vs looping):

- https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6
- https://www.datascience.com/blog/straightening-loops-how-to-vectorize-data-aggregation-with-pandas-and-numpy/
- https://realpython.com/numpy-array-programming/

Comment: Are the 15 minute intervals in the `datetime` object constant, or is this only an example? I.e. is this representative of your actual data?

Comment: Yes 15 min interval is just a simplification in this example

Comment: So are you looking for the last record by {symbol, exchange} that was created atleast 30min ago, or atmost 30 minutes ago? Because the solution will vary accordingly. (That is, what if you dont have an exact 30 minute match?)

Comment: 30 min is just an example, in real problem id be looking for corresponding record but created 1st of month, trailing quarters, and beginning of year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectorized!!!!!!!! (well... for the most part)

Idea is, use **"merge" (self join)** as supposed to "DataFrame.**lookup**" which is for entirely different application such as: [Pandas DataFrame.lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583677/pandas-dataframe-lookup/52583747?noredirect=1#comment92102660_52583747)

Extending from original fix ...

**STEP 1)** ProfitLoss.py \ **to_dict** to pre-calculate TM1, MonthStart, QuarterStart, YearStart - since this is going to be called anyway.

```
import datetime
import time
import math

from Util import ObjectUtil
from Util import DateTimeUtil

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from Util import ObjectUtil

class ProfitLoss(object):
    def set(self, field, val):
        setattr(self, field, val)

    def to_dict(self):
        result = ObjectUtil.objectPropertiesToDictionary(self)
        result["TM1"] = self.COB - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        result["MonthStart"] = self.COB.replace(day=1)
        result["QuarterStart"] = DateTimeUtil.getQuarterStart(self.COB, self.COB.year)
        result["YearStart"] = datetime.datetime(self.COB.year, 1, 1)

        return result

    @staticmethod
    def from_dict(dict):
        if dict is None:
            return None

        profitLosses = []
        for k, v in dict.items():
            numPnl = len(v)
            for i in range(0, numPnl):
                pnl = ProfitLoss()
                profitLosses.append(pnl)
            break

        for k, v in dict.items():
            if k == "from_dict":
                break

            i = 0
            for val in v.values():
                if isinstance(val, pd.Timestamp):
                    val = datetime.datetime(val.year, val.month, val.day)

                val = None if val == np.nan else val

                if isinstance(val, float) and math.isnan(val):
                    val = None

                profitLosses[i].set(k, val)
                i+=1

        return profitLosses
```

**STEP 2)** merge (i.e. Self-join), instead of DataFrame.**apply** or DataFrame.**lookup**:

```
        pdPnl = pd.DataFrame.from_records([pnl.to_dict() for pnl in profitLosses])
        pdPnl = pdPnl.merge(pdPnl, how='inner', left_on=["TM1"], right_on=["COB"], suffixes = ('','_tm1'))
        pdPnl = pdPnl.merge(pdPnl, how='inner', left_on=["MonthStart"], right_on=["COB"], suffixes = ('','_MonthStart'))
        pdPnl = pdPnl.merge(pdPnl, how='inner', left_on=["QuarterStart"], right_on=["COB"], suffixes = ('','_QuaterStart'))
        pdPnl = pdPnl.merge(pdPnl, how='inner', left_on=["YearStart"], right_on=["COB"], suffixes = ('','_YearStart'))

        # Vectorized
        pdPnl["DTDRealizedPnl"] = pdPnl["InceptionRealizedPnl"] - pdPnl["InceptionRealizedPnl_tm1"]
        pdPnl["DTDUnrealizedPnl"] = pdPnl["InceptionUnrealizedPnl"] - pdPnl["InceptionUnrealizedPnl_tm1"]
        pdPnl["MTDRealizedPnl"] =  pdPnl["InceptionRealizedPnl"] - pdPnl["InceptionRealizedPnl_MonthStart"]
        pdPnl["MTDUnrealizedPnl"] = pdPnl["InceptionUnrealizedPnl"] - pdPnl["InceptionUnrealizedPnl_MonthStart"]
        pdPnl["YTDRealizedPnl"] = pdPnl["InceptionRealizedPnl"] - pdPnl["InceptionRealizedPnl_YearStart"]
        pdPnl["YTDUnrealizedPnl"] = pdPnl["InceptionUnrealizedPnl"] - pdPnl["InceptionUnrealizedPnl_YearStart"]

        # Not yet vectorized
        pdPnl["SharpeRatio"] = pdPnl.apply(lambda rw : PnlCalculatorBase.computeSharpeRatio(pdPnl, rw["COB"]), axis=1)
        pdPnl["MaxDrawDown"] = pdPnl.apply(lambda rw : PnlCalculatorBase.computeMaxDrawDown(pdPnl, rw["COB"]), axis=1)

        pnlDict = pdPnl.to_dict()
        updatedProfitLosses = ProfitLoss.ProfitLoss.from_dict(pnlDict)
```

Actually i am not sure if merge/self join's any more performant than explicit loops. Also, I still haven't figured what to do what **Sharpe Ratio** and **MaxDrawdown** though!! Panda's Windowing function don't seem to help...

People?! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I got it, here's my *real* code (So I am not posting everything). This will work (but not sure if this is implemented the **fastest** way).

I am using ***DataFrame.apply***. This is **NOT** **Vectorized** way, but should be a lot faster than looping in python. Can someone please kindly shed some light how to rewrite below in completely **vectorized** manner?

Referencing this article - https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6

... I can't wrap my mind around to rewrite in **vectorized** way, and given nature of lookup, I am beginning to feel that below cannot be **vectorized** (Glad if one of you can prove me wrong):

```
pdPnl = pd.DataFrame.from_records([ObjectUtil.objectPropertiesToDictionary(pnl) for pnl in profitLosses], columns=ObjectUtil.objectPropertiesToDictionary(profitLosses[0]).keys())
pdPnl["TM1"] = pdPnl.apply(lambda rw : rw["COB"] - timedelta(days=1) , axis=1)
pdPnl["MonthStart"] = pdPnl.apply(lambda rw : rw["COB"].replace(day=1), axis=1)
pdPnl["QuarterStart"] = pdPnl.apply(lambda rw : DateTimeUtil.getQuarterStart(rw["COB"], rw["COB"].year), axis=1)
pdPnl["YearStart"] = pdPnl.apply(lambda rw : datetime(rw["COB"].year, 1, 1), axis=1)
pdPnl["DTDRealizedPnl"] = pdPnl.apply(lambda rw : PnlCalculatorBase.computeField(pdPnl, rw["TM1"], rw["InceptionRealizedPnl"], "InceptionRealizedPnl"), axis=1)
pdPnl["DTDUnrealizedPnl"] = pdPnl.apply(lambda rw : PnlCalculatorBase.computeField(pdPnl, rw["TM1"], rw["InceptionUnrealizedPnl"], "InceptionUnrealizedPnl"), axis=1)
pdPnl["MTDRealizedPnl"] = pdPnl.apply(lambda rw : PnlCalculatorBase.computeField(pdPnl, rw["MonthStart"], rw["InceptionRealizedPnl"], "InceptionRealizedPnl"), axis=1)
pdPnl["MTDUnrealizedPnl"] = pdPnl.apply(lambda rw : PnlCalculatorBase.computeField(pdPnl, rw["MonthStart"], rw["InceptionUnrealizedPnl"], "InceptionUnrealizedPnl"), axis=1)
pdPnl["YTDRealizedPnl"] = pdPnl.apply(lambda rw : PnlCalculatorBase.computeField(pdPnl, rw["YearStart"], rw["InceptionRealizedPnl"], "InceptionRealizedPnl"), axis=1)
pdPnl["YTDUnrealizedPnl"] = pdPnl.apply(lambda rw : PnlCalculatorBase.computeField(pdPnl, rw["YearStart"], rw["InceptionUnrealizedPnl"], "InceptionUnrealizedPnl"), axis=1)

pdPnl["SharpeRatio"] = pdPnl.apply(lambda rw : PnlCalculatorBase.computeSharpeRatio(pdPnl, rw["COB"]), axis=1)
pdPnl["MaxDrawDown"] = pdPnl.apply(lambda rw : PnlCalculatorBase.computeMaxDrawDown(pdPnl, rw["COB"]), axis=1)

pnlDict = pdPnl.to_dict()  # Then convert back to List of ProfitLoss (Slow...)
```

The lookup functions are:

```
@staticmethod
def lookUpRow(pdPnl, cob):
    return pdPnl[pdPnl["COB"]==cob]

@staticmethod
def computeField(pdPnl, cob, todaysPnl, targetField):
    val = np.nan
    otherRow = PnlCalculatorBase.lookUpRow(pdPnl, cob)
    if otherRow is not None and otherRow[targetField].shape[0]>0:
        try:
            tm1InceptionRealizedPnl = otherRow[targetField].iloc[0]
            val = todaysPnl - tm1InceptionRealizedPnl
        except:
            # slow...
            errMsg = "Failed lookup for " + str(cob) + " " + targetField
            logging.error(errMsg)
            val = np.nan
    return val


@staticmethod
def computeSharpeRatio(pdPnl, cob):
    val = None
    pdPnl = pdPnl[(pdPnl['COB']<=cob)]
    pdPnl = pdPnl.loc[:,["COB", "DTDRealizedPnl","DTDUnrealizedPnl"]]
    pdPnl["TotalDTD"] = pdPnl.apply(lambda rw : rw["DTDRealizedPnl"] + rw["DTDUnrealizedPnl"], axis=1)

    # @todo, We don't have risk free rate for Sharpe Ration calc. Here's just total DTD avg return over standard deviation
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharpe_ratio
    mean = pdPnl["TotalDTD"].mean()
    std = pdPnl["TotalDTD"].std()
    val = mean / std

    return val

@staticmethod
def computeMaxDrawDown(pdPnl, cob):
    val = None
    pdPnl = pdPnl[(pdPnl['COB']<=cob) & (pdPnl["DTDRealizedPnl"]<0)]
    val = pdPnl["DTDRealizedPnl"].min()
    return val
```

Comment: **`pd.DataFrame.apply` is not vectorised**. It is nothing more than a thinly veiled loop and often slower than a list comprehension.

Comment: hi jpp, can you shed some light how you'd rewrite above more efficiently please?

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming `created` has constant 15-minute intervals. You can `groupby` symbol and exchange, and shift down by 2 (for 2 periods, since each period is 15 minutes):

```
dfSummary['30min_ago_spread'] = dfSummary.groupby(['symbol', 'exchange'])['spread'].shift(2)
```

Output:

```
   symbol exchange  balance   offer  spread  created               30min_ago_spread
0  ETHBTC  binance       10  0.0351 -0.0316  2018-09-01 08:15:00       NaN
1  ETHBTC  binance       10  0.0351 -0.0316  2018-09-01 08:30:00       NaN
2  ETHBTC  binance       10  0.0351 -0.0316  2018-09-01 08:45:00   -0.0316
3  LTCBTC  binance       10  0.0920 -0.0830  2018-09-01 08:15:00       NaN
4  LTCBTC  binance       10  0.0920 -0.0830  2018-09-01 08:30:00       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks but sorry can't use a simple shift with hard coded periods = 2. Above is simplistic illustration of actual problem, where look up is more like corresponding row created in 1st of month, quarter and year.